# String as a Single value and Array as multiple value handling

Tags: javascript, arrays, string

If I select one value the I am getting value is like

`val : "ABC"`

But if I select multiple value my val is comming in array

`val : ["ABC","DEF"].`

Now because of this problem is neighther I can work on for single value nor multiple. Can anybody tell me how to handle this.

eg:

```
var myObj = {
    data : "M1",
    val : "Abc"
}
```

After adding another value it become

```
var myObj = {
    data : "M2",
    val : Abc,Def
}
```

Comment: need code to know if I can help or not.

Comment: I will improve my question if you comment the reasion for downvote

Comment: Can you show us a bit of your code, where, when and how did you get first and second result?

Comment: Don't downvote you yet, but I can imagine why, your question lake of Code example to help you.

Comment: @shankysingh i didn't downvote your question bro. Stick to the question and improve it if you want help.

Comment: @FirozJaroli I added some data what I am getting from backend

Comment: @Leze I added some data what I am getting from backend

Comment: What did you except, and how do you add data to your object?

Comment: By selection of another combobox value is getting add in MyObj Value

Comment: @shankysingh . Dude , forget about your code . Create an example with simple code and add CLEARLY what do you want to achieve

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function handleVal(val){
  if ("string" === typeof val){
  console.log("Do sth with string");
  } else if (Array.isArray(val)){
    console.log("Do sth with array")
  }
}

handleVal("ABC");
handleVal([1,2])
```